# RegEx to match if string should contain ';' before and after particular string

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following expression:

```regex
"?:(.*);GRAYSCALE=([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:;\\w*)?"
```

```
1. Input: GRAYSCALE=(120) --> Expected output: true
2. Input: GRAYSCALE=(120); --> Expected output: true
3. Input: GRAYSCALE=(120);abcd --> Expected output: true
4. Input: GRAYSCALE=(120)abcd --> Expected output: false
5. Input: abGRAYSCALE=(120); --> Expected output: false
6. Input: abc;GRAYSCALE=(120);acx --> Expected output: true
```

For cases `1` - `4` I am getting the correct output, but not for `5` and `6`.

Comment: please post the working regex.

Comment: RegEx : "?:(.*);GRAYSCALE=([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:;\\w*)?"                                                                     I am getting correct output for above regex. Only if I am adding anything before GRAYSCALE, returns false.

Comment: That cannot be a working regex.there is no `\\(` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a word boundary to the start and make the `;` at the first as optional. And also you must need to add the patterns to match `()` opening and closing parentheses.

```
(.*?)\\b;?GRAYSCALE=\\(([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\)(?:;\\w*)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lL8jC1/1)

```
String[] inputs = {
        "GRAYSCALE=(120)",// -- Expected output: True
        "GRAYSCALE=(120);",// -- Expected output: True
        "GRAYSCALE=(120);abcd",// -- Expected output: True
        "GRAYSCALE=(120)abcd",// -- Expected output: False
        "abGRAYSCALE=(120)",// -- Expected output: False
        "abc;GRAYSCALE=(120);acx" // --> Expected output: true
};

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\b;?GRAYSCALE=\\(([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\)(?:;\\w*)?$");
for (String input: inputs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    System.out.printf("%s found? %b%n", input, m.find());
}
```

**Output:**

```
GRAYSCALE=(120) found? true
GRAYSCALE=(120); found? true
GRAYSCALE=(120);abcd found? true
GRAYSCALE=(120)abcd found? false
abGRAYSCALE=(120) found? false
abc;GRAYSCALE=(120);acx found? true
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lL8jC1/2)

Answer (score 4):

Why do this with one regex? Use several tools:

```
private static final Pattern SEMICOLON = Pattern.compile(";");
private static final Pattern GRAYSCALE 
    = Pattern.compile("GRAYSCALE=\\((\\d+\\))");

// Test...
final String[] splits = SEMICOLON.split(input);

Matcher matcher;
boolean found = false;
String inParens;
int number;

for (final String candidate: splits) {
    matcher = GRAYSCALE.matcher(candidate);
    if (!matcher.find())
        continue;
    inParens = matcher.group(1);
    try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(inParens);
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // overflow
        continue;
    }
}

// test "number" here
```

If you use Java 8, here is some lambda abuse (with `SEMICOLON` and `GRAYSCALE` defined as above):

```
final Optional<String> opt = SEMICOLON.splitAsStream().map(GRAYSCALE::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::find).map(m -> m.group(1)).findFirst();

if (!opt.isPresent()) {
    // no luck
}

try {
    Integer.parseInt(opt.get());
    // Found at least an integer
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // overflow
}
```

Comment: i don't know what's the reason for op putting a number check condition on his regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj me neither; looks like an integer between 0 and 255 is wanted and this can be done far more efficiently OUTSIDE of the regex, that's for sure